# java.lang.NullPointerException with cursor

Tags: android, cursor, nullpointerexception

I've two .java files: `Read.java` and `Save.java`. And I'm getting a `NullPointerException` when I try to launch my application. Logcat entries refer to both

`Cursor cu = cr.query(URI, null, null, null, null);` and

`rc.Cont(destination.getAbsolutePath());` as the cause of NullPointerException.

But, I've already try `Read.java` apart and it's working fine as I except to. I guess, it's the call from another class which is doing trouble. Thanks for help.

--`Read.java`

```
public class ReadCon(String destination) {

`...`

     public void Cont(String destination) {

           ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

           Cursor cu = cr.query(URI, null, null, null, null);

           ...

     }

}
```

--`Save.java`

```
public class SaveEnd extends Activity {

    File destination;

    Fonctions f = new Fonctions();

    //creerDossier return type is File

    destination = f.creerDossier(2, Save.pathsList[i]);

ReadCon rc = new ReadCon();

rc.Cont(destination.getAbsolutePath()); 

}
```

This is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException

at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:91)
at projet.sarelo.ReadContacts.SaveContacts(Read.java:134)
at projet.sarelo.SaveEnd.onStart(Save.java:75)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1132)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4320)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1709)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: As Jack said, post the stack trace.  There is some code missing, so it's hard to tell, but what is "destination"  are you instantiating it prior to calling getAbsolutePath()?

Comment: @hooked82 destination is a File instance.

Comment: I've also put the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Thanks all for help. Somehow, the `getContentResolver()` called from

`cont(String destination)` was returning `null` in `SaveEnd` class. I've used a `Context` instance to set it right. This is my final code

```
public class ReadCon {
    public void Cont(File destination, Context c) {
       ContentResolver cr = c.getContentResolver();
       Cursor cu = cr.query(URI, null, null, null, null);
    }
}


public class SaveEnd extends Activity {
    Context c = this;
    ReadCon rc = new ReadCon();
    rc.Cont(destination, c); 
}
```